# Report Viewer with Server 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, windows-server-2008, reportviewer2008

I was doing project in MVC3. In that I was using SSRS reports. The reports are working fine in development system. But when deploying with Windows Server (With Sql Server Report services Configured), then throwing error message (**RSclientController** is undefined).

For the above error i googled a bit and found the problem because of ReportViewerHandler. So I have triedto include the handler config to the handler Mappings in IIS7.

But in the default available handlers, the ReportViewer 9.0 is not there. so I dont know which installer do i need to install for this. Can you anyone tell me which ReportViewer installer do i need to install to make this working.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable.  I *think* that 2008 is v9, but I could be mistaken; not somewhere I can check at the moment, sorry.

- 2008 SP1:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3841
- 2008:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6576